# TuneUp Utilities make my Internet Explorer fault

Tags: internet-explorer, cleaning, javascript

I ran [TuneUp Utilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TuneUp_Utilities) and then my Internet Explorer could no longer run a page with [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

I think it removes some important registry entries.

I tried to update Internet Explorer, but it didn't help.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: http://bash.org/?915082

Answer (score 1):

In the process somewhere did your JavaScript get turned off? It should be enabled.

e.g. item #1 in this screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can vouch for TU most likely not causing a problem with IE. I have been using it for 2 years bi-weekly for all of my system cleanup needs. Try updating windows and cleaning it with TU registry cleaner and CCLeaner registry cleaner.

Comment: Just because it works for you doesn't mean it works for everyone.

Comment: We use it in our business environment. TU is has never been the cause of any problems. If anything it's fixing them.

Answer (score 0):

My scripting is already enabled.

I removed Internet Explorer and installed it again, it didn't help.

I test by simple HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            alert('test');
        </script>
    </body>
```